# Dynamic arrays and lists

Tags: java, arrays, list

So, I'm trying to create a kind of text editor for creating question lists. I'm unsure how to achieve that.

What I came up with until now is to create a JPanel which represents an A4 piece of paper. Then, I'd like to create maybe another JPanel which would contain several textboxes in which question/answers would be typed in. The problem is that I'd like to be able to add/remove questions from anywhere within my "document". Doing it with arrays would be tedious and I'd survive that, but the main issue would be fixed array size.

My question is, is there any way to create some kind of dynamic list and what would be a way to go in my case? It's also important to be able to pinpoint a certain "question" JPanel by simply invoking any of its textboxes (because clicking a textbox and pressing a combination of keys would add another question after the invoked one, at least that's the plan).

Anyone?

Comment: Do you mean something like an ArrayList? - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `collections`, from `java.util.collection` package.

**1.** If every question you create has a unique identifier attached to it, then try to use `Map`, where let an `Integer` be your unique identifier and `String` may be the question

```
Map<Integer, String> map = HashMap<Integer, String>();
```

**2.** If you are storing the question is in `sequence`, `List` may also suffice.

`List<String> list = ArrayList<String>();`

Comment: There is no `java.util.collection` package. The collection classes are in the package `java.util`.

Comment: Hmmm, ArrayList seem like it would do the job, but it would also be nice if I could differenciate between several types of questions in my arraylist. I could achieve that bay creating a complex data type containing JPanel and intereg indicating question type, but is there another, maybe simpler or faster way of achieving that?

Comment: Try using `HashMap<Integer, Array<String>>` Each Integer will specify a `certain type` of Question, and Array<String> will have the Questions attached to that Integer in the list

Comment: Itz will have to be `Array<JPanel>`, but I guess it should work either way...

BTW, HashMap is faster than my idea, right?

Comment: Collections gives better flexibility than arrays, thats for sure... Among Maps HashMap is fastest, but if its about ArrayList and HashMap , then its not abt the quickness but the purpose. ArrayList maintains Sequence, and HashMap key-value pair

Comment: Well, sequence is more important for me, and key-value pair can be mantained with more complex data type. I guess then that my initial idea would serve the purpose better, maybe even be the only way, in this case atleast.

Comment: Well i have laid down the advantages and differences, now its ur call....... i hope you will make a good choice

Comment: You can always create your own class and put it into the array list.  Then that class can have The question, the answer, the question type and any other fields or pieces of information you want your questions to have.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I intended and what I decided to do. =)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [ArryList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html). There are also many other collection classes in [the util package](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/List.html) that are also worth looking at. However, if you do not need a List and would like to be able to retrieve your Object by a known key a [HashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/index.html?java/util/List.html) would be a better choice. For instance you should be able to use a JPanel or a TextField as the key.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)?

You could also use a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to have a key and then the JPanel as an instance?

It sounds like an ArrayList is better and then you generate a new JPanel biased on the Object/String in the ArrayList when it is clicked on.